# Wordpress Contact form 7 date format incorrect

Tags: wordpress, date, contact-form

I am using contact form 7 with wordpress 4.2. The problem I am having is that when a mail is received it is in US format: 2015-01-23. My site settings are english UK and on the form the date picker defaults to dd/mm/yyyy but mails I am receiving are in the format of US. I have tried date-format:dd/mm/yy in the tag, but it still arrives as US. This is the latest attempt:

```
<p>Date of Event: (Required)<br />
[date* date-387 _format_your-date "D, d M y"]
</p>
```

and the mail tag

```
Date of event: 
[date-387]
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me to correct this to UK format. Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind that "2015-01-23" isn't US format, it's [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, specifically designed to avoid ambiguities among international date formats. The normal US format would be month-day-year order, not year-month-day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://contactform7.com/date-field/):

> Format Date Value in Mail
>
> As previously explained, if a value is specified in a date field, the value must be in YYYY-MM-DD format (e.g. 2013-04-08). When the value is inserted into mail template, the date format keeps by default. **To change the format in mail, you can use a variant of mail-tag notation `[_format_{field name} "{date format}"]`**.

So, to change the format for mail, you need to give a date format to your *mail* tag. This is separate from any formatting you apply to form fields.

Note also that you're meant to replace "your-date" in the examples with the name of your actual field, so for example, your mail tag should be:

```
[_format_date-387 "D, d M y"]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there a way however, to change it to say 29/05/2015. Thanks

Comment: Yeah; you can format it by specifying the format string (the bit at the end) according to PHP's [date function specification](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)—I'd think that "d/m/Y" should do it.

Comment: Cheers matt. Very much appreciated.